# Spring MVC: Including a JSP inside a view (JSP is installed next to view so is inaccesible from outside controller)?

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have created a view and its working well but i now need to Include another JSP inside the page.

Considering my views are installed in the protected area of WEB-INF/Views (hence its not available in my resources directory where my imgs, css are)

I have tried using

```
   <%@ include file="/views/shared/items/NewItem.jsp" %>
```

And it always gives me FileNotFound, taking into consideration that my NewItem.jsp is installed with my other views (i.e. NOT accesible via the normal routes but controlled by controllers) how can i include a JSP files that is installed next to my view

If i take out the "include file" my view renders without issues.

I am sure i am missing something here?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If `NewItem.jsp` is in `/WEB-INF/views/shared/items/NewItem.jsp`, then you have to use this path when incuding it:

```
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/views/shared/items/NewItem.jsp" %>
```

Comment: It's not inherently good or bad. Tags can be a better idea sometimes, and it shouldn't replace a layout engine.

Answer (score 4):

Better to user

```
<jsp:include />
```

instead of

```
<%@ include />
```

and send request to controller and controller will handle view

Sending request to contoller

```
    <jsp:include page="${request.contextPath}/newItem"></jsp:include>
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "newItem")
public String newItem(Model model) {
    return "shared/items/NewItem";
}
```

Comment: Why is it better?