# How to include JSP in Spring MVC contoller rather than forward?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

In my Spring MVC controller, I have a single method process():

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/Foo/dash")
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping( params = "action=loadDashboard") 
    public String process() {
        return "/Moo/dash/bar";
    }
}
```

It is my understanding that in this case, upon hitting the return statement, Spring MVC will perform a forward to the specified JSP file.

How can I change the return statement, and/or the method, so that instead of a forward, Spring MVC will perform an include of the specified JSP?

Comment: You cannot - I don't think you understand how a JSP works. It is compiled to Java source code by a JSP compiler and then compiled to a `.class` by javac. A JSP is actually a standalone servlet - requests **must** be forwarded to a JSP. If you want to avoid the forward; use a templating library.

Comment: Where do you want to include jsp file?

Comment: There's a similar question answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39465193/how-do-i-render-a-spring-viewjsp-in-a-div-tag-after-submit-a-form

Comment: maybe you mean like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/28989249/3959856

Comment: @Boris the Spider, I'm kinda familiar with JSP's. Not so familiar with Spring. But, FYI, requests may include JSP's , not just be forwarded to JSP's.